# Ionic 4 Popover implementation Error: No component factory found for ProfileComponent

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to implement the popover in ionic 4 and it's displaying this error for me, I've created a unique component for the popover and I'm implementing on the page, so I click the button to create the component it gives this error.

I'm using lazy loading and importing the module into the files, what am I doing wrong?

```
ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for ProfileComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

PopoverModule

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ProfileComponent } from './profile.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ProfileComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [ProfileComponent],
})
export class ProfileModule { }
```

PageModule:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ProfilePage } from './profile.page';
import { ValidationSummaryComponent } from '../../../components/validation-summary/validation-summary.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from '../../../components/popovers/profile/profile.component';
import { IonicSelectableModule } from 'ionic-selectable';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProfilePage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    IonicSelectableModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    ProfileComponent,
    ProfilePage, 
    ValidationSummaryComponent, 
  ]
})
export class ProfilePageModule {}
```

Page.ts method for create popover:

```js
import { ProfileComponent } from '../../../components/popovers/profile/profile.component';      
async openPopover(ev: any) {
        const popover = await this.popoverCtrl.create({
          component: ProfileComponent,
          event: ev,
          translucent: true
        });
        return await popover.present();
      }
```

Comment: can you show the place you imported PopoverModule and PageModule

Comment: You don't need a profile module. Delete the profile module. Your page module seems fine.

Comment: I delete the profile module but the error continues, I popovermodule in the paginia module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create your component from **Page.ts** you should declare your component as entry component in **PageModule** :

```js
declarations: [
    ...,
    ProfileComponent,
],
entryComponents: [ProfileComponent]
```

---

#### [UPDATE 6/11/2020]

With Angular 9, `entryComponents` will not be needed anymore. See [this link](https://ionicframework.com/blog/angular-9-0-0-and-ivy-improvements/) for more info

Comment: Thank you my friend, to run I added the component at declarations and entryComponents.

Comment: Adding my Popover module to the entryComponents AND declarations list fixed it, thanks! Supposedly with Angular 9 entryComponents will no longer be needed